# add a custom view/windows in the mac os X dock

Tags: cocoa, macos

I would like to add a custom view (a pager) in the dock, just before the trash and was wondering on how to perform a such task.

Do you have any pointer to help me to start?

Thanks in advance for your help :)

regards,

Comment: You can't put an application on the documents/folders/Trash side of the Dock. Even if you find a way, it'd be a hack you couldn't rely on. At best, you'd simply get kicked back to the applications side of the line at some point; at worst, you'd break users' Docks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `NSDockTile` class, and specifically the [`contentView` property](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSDockTile_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005255-RH2-tryLock). You access this through `NSApplication`'s `dockTile` accessor. You can set a custom view to display in the dock. Keep in mind, though, that the user can make the dock very small, so you can't assume your icon will be at any particular size.

The [Dock Tile Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html) has some pointers to get you started.